# Can parse.com act as a replacement to XMPP Server

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am in the process of building a cross platform messaging application which has file sharing and other features as well. Using parse.com i was hoping to avoid writing a XMPP based server as the middle layer.
Is this a correct assumption to make that if I use parse.com then the infrastructure should be sufficient enough for creating a complete messaging application?

Comment: Parse.com gives a maximum of 400 request per second, I you have that much of traffic then I think it will be a problem. Also I think they are having the costliest rates

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your assumption is correct. Parse.com will be enough to implement your initial requirements.

- use [ParseUser](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users) for users stuff;
- use [Push notifications](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android) to notify about new messages;
- use [ParseFile](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#files) to handle sharing of files.

But keep in mind [price](https://parse.com/plans) for that. I guess, Free plan will be enough at initial state, but later when your project will require more, you'll need to pay.

So you need to think about it and weight all +/-

Comment: I have already seen that all these features are available but the push notifications from Parse do not seem to be reliable. I guess it has an accuracy of about 75-80% which might not be sufficient if you heavily rely on notifications. Is there a way to overcome this limitation?

Comment: @Anuj where did you get number 75-80% of accuracy?

Comment: HAve been testing the features on Parse.com for a couple of months now. Earlier i thought it was due to the app being marked as development but i also tried marking the app on parse.com as a production app. Did not create a difference

Comment: I see, you still can implement querying of Message class by some interval as alternative.

Comment: @Anuj you can view [Parse Push notifications Troubleshooting](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#troubleshooting/Android), you didn't do that yeat

Comment: I have already gone through that guide as well. I am using the latest SDK and everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parse in a more efficient way as compared to XMPP server.
Parse offers Product as a service, it can be used as a backend server and can integrate with facebook and twitter too.
Either you can use parse login or create your own account service using JSON.
Me and my friend used it as a cloud server for our app.

Comment: A complete messaging service can be used with twiio, if yo are only intended for messaging service.

Comment: Twilio is more focused towards SMS and Voip kind of stuff.

Comment: Yes if you specify what type of service you want to create then its easy to get your point.

Comment: Let us assume that i am looking to create a Whattsapp like messaging app.

Comment: Depends on your needs,  First case you have enough time to manage your own server and update each little tweak this is using XMPP.                                                   Second thing a server like  Parse or Google App Engine which reduces your effort but you have to pay a amount to them.     It gives you power of push, analytics and much more.                   Surely you can use it as a more powerful server but choice is yours.    :)                                                                  If Need any other info let me know.

Comment: I think that reinventing a wheel is only necessary if you have something new or different solution as compared to others.